# Changing the distribution from uniform random number generator

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a random number generator:

```
rand()
```

Each time I call this function it gives me a number between $0.0$ to $1.0$.

I need a number between $(0.0)$ to $(1000.0)$ while `1000.0 * rand()` just gives me a uniform distribution within this range.

My desired distribution is something that gives me an equal chance to either of these ranges:

- range of 0 to 1
- range of 1 to 10
- range of 10 to 100
- range of 100 to 1000

Though an option is to use a piecewise function to produce such a distribution, or using `exp(.)`, is there any other standard method to produce such a distribution?

Comment: If you accept to change the range of 0 to 1 to the range from 0.1 to 1 then a simple option is to consider `10^(4*rand()-1)`.

Comment: do you want a uniform distribution between those ranges?  - how about generate a random number 1,2,3,4 then use that to select one of 4 different functions for your 4 distributions - that is valid since all random numbers are assumed unrelated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to generate, for example, 1-10, you can use 1 + rand(9)

In general to generate between a-b you can use a + rand(b-a)

Comment: That is not what I want. For example (0+rand(1000)) is 10 times more likely to be between 100 to 1000 than between 10 to 100.